# Custom "code templates" in Intelli J

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm moving to IntelliJ from NetBeans for a class I'm teaching. NB has a nice feature that allows one to enter a custom defined string such as 'sout' and by using Code Completion, will expand to 'System.out.println()'.

I don't see an equivalent mechanism in IntelliJ, but I may well be missing it/not asking the right question of Google.

I do see macros, but that's not quite what I want.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Bo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes just speaking the question out loud makes the answer easier to find.

[Live Templates is what IntelliJ calls them.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-code-constructs-by-live-templates.html)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: The question was, "Can someone point me in the right direction?" All I needed was the pointer. The answer is "Live Templates". While it is true that the link may go stale over time, an "IntelliJ Live Templates" search on google will presumably reveal a plethora of JetBrains links. Rather than reproduce what is surely copyrighted material, I used the link as it was intended - to point to the definitive source.